# Can I remove massive DFOptimize_#.bin files from C:\?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, defragment, ccleaner

There are about 50 of these `DFOptimize_1.bin` files, each with a different number (DFOptimize_1.bin, DFOptimize_2.bin, etc.) in my `C:/` drive. From my research, it looked like these were connected to CCleaner or other Defragmentation software.

All of these files (except DFOptimize_51.bin) are exactly 1,073,741,824 bytes which in total, takes up a massive amount of space on my PC. Therefore, I'd like to find out if I can safely remove these files or not.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvoZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to find out if I can safely remove these files or not.

You don’t specifically indicate if you have a SSD, but the optimize feature of Defraggler, forces a Trim operation when it’s ran on a SSD.

Creating temporary files and then removing them is one way to accomplish this task.  However, the files are not created by Windows, nor are they used by Windows.

The files in question were created by third-party software specifically by Defraggler.  Feel free to delete the files, provided Defraggler is not currently running, they serve no purpose if that’s the case.